# delete_vertices igraph in R

Tags: r, nodes, igraph

I need to remove from the graph the group with the greatest number of nodes. I try to use the delete_vertices(name_of_graph, nodes_to_remove), but how can I indicate the nodes to remove?
Ex. I have 5 groups with 6, 19, 27, 11, and 18 nodes. So I need to remove the group with 27 nodes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `delete.vertices()` function, you give the name of the graph and the name of the nodes you want to delete.

```
set.seed(666)
require(igraph)
net  = data.frame(
Node.1 = sample(LETTERS[1:15], 15, replace = TRUE),
Node.2 = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 15, replace = TRUE))

g <- igraph::graph_from_data_frame(net, directed = FALSE )
plot(g)
g = delete.vertices(g, V(g)$name == "N")
plot(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below using `components` to label groups and find the one with largest number of vertices. Then you use `subset` to filter out those vertices and apply `delete.vertices` to remove them.

```
delete.vertices(
  g,
  subset(
    V(g),
    with(components(g), membership == which.max(csize))
  )
)
```

---

**Example**

```
g1 <- make_ring(5)
g2 <- make_ring(3)
g3 <- make_ring(7)
g4 <- make_ring(4)

g <- disjoint_union(g1, g2, g3, g4)

plot(g)
```

[image]

After running

```
g.out <- delete.vertices(
  g,
  subset(
    V(g),
    with(components(g), membership == which.max(csize))
  )
)

plot(g.out)
```

you will see

[image]